# Is there an antonym for "pejorative"?

Tags: vocabulary, antonyms

Perhaps "compliment", but are there any other ideas?

Comment: Complimentary, praising.

Comment: Several online dictionaries provide synonyms and antonyms.  Consult those first, and then if none of the possibilities offered there meets your needs, ask here, explaining why.

Comment: Etymologically, _pejorative_ comes from Latin _peior_ 'worse'. Its opposite is _melior_ 'better'. So an antonym could be _meliorative_, with or without an initial _a_-.

Comment: @TimRomano I think this is a good question because the online thesauruses I scoured don't capture the connotation of "pejorative." Pejorative implies unnecessarily negative, while words like "complimentary" or "lauding" don't imply that at all.

Comment: @Faraz Abidi: Why do you think pejorative implies *unnecessarily* negative, or that it has anything to do with undeserved criticism?  Also, I am not sure what you mean by "that".  Are you suggesting that the antonym should imply "undeserved praise"? Or would the antonym mean "deservéd praise"?

Comment: @TimRomano Yes, I think the antonym should imply undeserved praise. http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pejorative Merriam Webster describes pejorative as "disparaging" or "belittling" which are not the features of level-headed criticism.

Comment: @Faraz Abidi: OK. So you would say the question is: What is a word that means "to bestow praise on something that does not deserve it"?

Comment: @TimRomano Yes, I think that would be fair.

Comment: @Faraz Abidi: something like *sycophantic* or *fawning*?

Answer (score 7):

The fancy latinate term having the opposite sense to *perjorative* is ***approbative***.

From Wiktionary:

> ***approbative***: *A word or grammatical form which denotes a positive affect expressing the appreciation or approval of the speaker.*

From the Collaborative International Dictionary of English:

> ***approbative*** (adj.): *Approving, or implying approbation.*

From the Century Dictionary and Cyclopedia:

> ***approbative***: *Approving; expressing, implying, or of the nature of approbation.*

Answer (score 1):

When I think of an antonym for pejorative, ameliorative comes to mind.

> to make or become better, more bearable, or more satisfactory; improve

Also, just an anecdote but FWIW in my English classes we would break a word or concept into a t-chart with its respective  *pejorative* and *ameliorative* connotations.

Comment: What's a t-chart and what level of English language?

Comment: @Mitch A t-chart is when you simply draw a lower-case 't' and then put two words on top of the t's arms and underneath you write related opinions for the respective terms underneath the arms.  This was used in my English courses in high school and college (American).

Answer (score 0):

I've been using 'meliorative' for years...I'm a secondary English teacher in the UK, though this in itself does not mean I'm correct...

Comment: Please use the answer box to explain why your word is a good choice.

Answer (score -1):

Online thesauruses list answers like "praising" or "complimentary," and while these are technically antonyms, they don't really capture the connotation of pejorative.
Merriam Webster describes pejorative as "disparaging" or "belittling" which are not the features of level-headed criticism.
   http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pejorative
  Pejoratives implies unnecessary or unfair hostility towards a subject (e.g. if you use the pejorative "thinkpiece" to refer to an article, you are mocking it as being pretentious) so I think an antonym should feature a similar level of unnecessary praise.

I think something like "flattery" or its synonyms.
http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/flattery